# Find pairs of elements in order in terms of distance

Tags: python, list, distance

Suppose we have data a₁, ..., aₙ,  where n is an even integer and each aᵢ ∈ ℝ. Also define the distance between two pairs of elements dis(aᵢ, aⱼ) = | aᵢ − aⱼ |. Now the program should output a list of pairs of elements sorted by the distance in an ascending order. Also the program should pack the input data into pairs, therefore each element aᵢ would only appear once in the output.

For example, given the input [1, 0.4, 3, 1.1] the output should be [(1, 1.1), (0.4, 3)].

A naive brute-force method is to calculate all C(n,2) pair and sorted the distance of each pair.

```py
def not_in_list_of_pair(i, ls):
    return not i in [p[0] for p in ls] + [p[1] for p in ls]

def calc(ls):
    ls = sorted(ls)
    d ={}
    for idx1, i in enumerate(ls[:-1]):
        for idx2, j in enumerate(ls[idx1+1:], idx1 + 1):
            d[(i,j)] = j - i
            
    # 2nd part
    res = []
    for pair in sorted(d, key = lambda k: d[k]):
        i, j = pair
        if not_in_list_of_pair(i, res) and not_in_list_of_pair(j, res):
            res.append(pair)
    return res

# another example
ls = [1, 0.1, 2, 2.4, 3, 4, 1.5]
assert calc(ls) == [(2, 2.4), (1, 1.5), (3, 4)]
```

But this naive method only works in O(n²), and the 2nd part (extracting min distance) is also slow. Therefore I am looking for a more effective method to solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Manhattan distance is calculated between two points

Comment: @deadshot Oh sorry for the confusion. I originally thought that the absolute value distance is a special case of Manhattan distance.

Comment: you have to check for every combination there is no alternative. one thing you can do is use `set` instead of `list`

Comment: It feels like this should be doable in O(n log n) time, but it'd be a bit of finesse to get it all out without ever scanning the list in a loop.

Comment: @deadshot - Since the problem is one-dimensional, the array can be sorted then closest pair will be adjacent to each other.

Comment: Sort is O(n log n), and getting the pair-wise distances out in sorted order feels like it ought to be doable with a priority queue (`heapq` module) also in O(n log n).

Comment: @sabik how do you handle negative numbers

Comment: @deadshot - No special handling is needed for negative numbers? When you sort the list, they get sorted where they should be, and the rest of the code would work with pair-wise differences, which will all be positive.

Answer (score 2):

I have to say that your descrption of the problem is not clear and the complexity in the description is not correct, i.e., you have to calculate the distance of all the pairs of integers (which is O(n^2)) and after that you sort all the distance (which is O(n^2 * log(n^2))).

For this problem, you are basically finding two integers with smallest distance, pick these two integers out, and repeat the same process on the remaining integers.

One naive solution is, supposed the integers are ***sorted***, and we only find one pair of integers with smallest distance, then we just need to calculate the distance of each two **adjacent** integers (e.g., dist between `ls[0]` and `ls[1]`, between `ls[1]` and `ls[2]`, ..., between `ls[n - 2]` and `ls[n - 1]`) and find out which pair is the smallest. After we find one, remove the two selected integers, the remaining integers are still sorted. If we want to find the next pair of integers with smallest distance, the problem remains the same.

The naive solution is still expensive in two aspsects: (1) we need to calculate the distance of each two adjacent integers each time; (2) we need to remove two integers from a sorted array and keep the array sorted.

To solve (1), in fact, we don't have to calculate the all the distances each time. E.g., suppose we have 6 integers where we calculated dist(0, 1), dist(1, 2), dist(2, 3), dist(3, 4), dist(4, 5). We find that the 2nd and the 3rd integers are the closet ones, so we output and remove the 2nd and the 3rd integers. For the next round, we need to calculate dist(0, 1), dist(1, 4), dist(4, 5). We can see that we only need to remove dist(1, 2) and dist(3, 4) as they're useless, but we need to add a new distance dist(1, 4) while dist(0, 1) and dist(4, 5) are not changed. We can maintain a btree to achieve the purpose.

To solve (2), the best data structure where we can remove items from the middle is double linked list with complexity O(1). But we are using array now and we may not want to change array to linked list. One way is that we use **index array** to mimic a double linked list.

Here is an example.

Update 1: I found `OrderedDict` does not pop the minimal item each time. I don't find any data structure in python that works as btree. I have to use a heap where I cannot delete those useless distance but I can identiy and ignore them. Sorry for the mistake.

Update 2: Add a `else` branch in the `while` loop, i.e., we should not change the double linked list when we see a useless item.

Update 3: Just realize that the heap will have no more than `n` items in each iteration in the while loop. So the complexity is roughly O(n log n), with n being the number of integers.

```py
from heapq import *

def calc(ls):
  ls = sorted(ls) # O(nlogn)
  n = len(ls)

  # mimic a double linked list
  left = [i - 1 for i in range(n)]
  right = [i + 1 for i in range(n)]
  appeared = [False for i in range(n)]

  btree = []
  for i in range(0, n - 1):
    # distance of adjacent integers, and their indices
    heappush(btree, (ls[i + 1] - ls[i], i, i + 1))

  # roughly O(n log n), because the heap will have at most `n` items in each iteration
  result = []
  while len(btree) != 0:
    minimal = heappop(btree)
    a, b = minimal[1:3]

    # skip if either a or b appeared
    if not appeared[a] and not appeared[b]:
      result.append((ls[a], ls[b]))
      appeared[a] = True
      appeared[b] = True
    else:
      continue # this is important
    #print result

    if left[a] != -1:
      right[left[a]] = right[b]
    if right[b] != n:
      left[right[b]] = left[a]
    if left[a] != -1 and right[b] != n:
      heappush(btree, (ls[right[b]] - ls[left[a]], left[a], right[b]))

  return result

ls = [1, 0.1, 2, 2.4, 3, 4, 1.5]
print calc(ls)
```

With the following output:

```
[(2, 2.4), (1, 1.5), (3, 4)]
Note: The number of input integers is 7, which is NOT even.
```

Show one more image to present what is going on:
[image]

I am not very familiar with Python, so I may not be using the best data structure in the above code snippet.

Comment: This should be O(n log n), I think. (Assuming `sorted()` is O(n log n), which is probably an acceptable assumption whether or not it's true.)